# Binary search in elisp, do away with the return variable

Tags: search

As part of my efforts to spruce up my elisp fundas, I am trying to implement the basic algorithms in elisp. I have done for binary search program as follows,

```el
(defun bnry-srch (vctr itm strt end)
  "Searches for the item ITM in the vector VCTR. strt is usually 0
  and end is vctr's length-1"
  (setq ret -1)
  (if (>= end strt) 
      (let ((mid (/ (+ strt end ) 2)))
        (if (= (aref vctr mid) itm)
            (setq ret mid)
          (if (> (aref vctr mid) itm)
              (setq ret (bnry-srch vctr itm strt (1- mid)))
            (setq ret (bnry-srch vctr itm (1+ mid) end))))))
  ret)
```

Above function can be invoked as,

```
(bnry-srch [1 2 3 4 5] 2 0 4)
```

It works with a convincing accuracy. But that excess use of variable, `ret` because elisp doesn't have a return statement is a bit intriguing to me. Is there a way, that can be done away with?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm looks to me like this:

```el
(defun bnry-srch (vctr itm strt end)
  "Searches for the item ITM in the vector VCTR. strt is usually 0
and end is vctr's length-1"
  (if (>= end strt)
      (let ((mid (/ (+ strt end ) 2)))
        (if (= (aref vctr mid) itm)
            mid
          (if (> (aref vctr mid) itm)
              (bnry-srch vctr itm strt (1- mid))
            (bnry-srch vctr itm (1+ mid) end))))
    -1))
```

For completeness, also read <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Catch and Throw` -- but you didn't need that here.

Comment: Check also Jon Bentley's "Programming Pearls" column on binary search and related matters: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/358172.358176